# Batch Script is exporting weird characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd, output, character, wmic

I am having an issue with a script. I will post it.
It runs fine till it gets to this line:

```
wmic diskdrive list full | findstr /B "Size=" >> %cd%ProductCodes\%Serial%\PCINFO.txt
```

This is what it sends to the file...
楓敺ㄽ㐲ㄱ㈱㤴㈹ര਍楓敺㈽㘵㔰㤲㘶〴ര਍

Any help would be appreciated

```
    set drive=%cd:~0,3%
@echo off
for /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('wmic systemenclosure get serialnumber /FORMAT:csv') do (set "serial=%%A")
mkdir %cd%ProductCodes\%Serial%
 wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey >> %cd%ProductCodes\%Serial%\Code.txt
wmic computersystem get model,manufacturer >> %cd%ProductCodes\%Serial%\PCINFO.txt
wmic cpu get name >> %cd%ProductCodes\%Serial%\PCINFO.txt
wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory >> %cd%ProductCodes\%Serial%\PCINFO.txt
wmic diskdrive list full | findstr /B "Size=" >> %cd%ProductCodes\%Serial%\PCINFO.txt


 cls
 More %cd%ProductCodes\%Serial%\Code.txt
 ECHO Open Windows Authentication?
 Echo Y/N
 SET /P M=Make Choice then press ENTER:
IF %M%==N GOTO :message
IF %M%==n GOTO :message
IF %M%==y GOTO :Start
IF %M%==Y GOTO :Start

:Start
start "C:\Windows\System32" slui.exe 3
 pause
 
 
 
 :message
 CLS
 ECHO Done!!
 pause
```

Here is the requested output I get

Manufacturer  Model
HP            HP ZBook 15 G5
Name
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz
TotalPhysicalMemory
16977272832
楓敺ㄽ㐲ㄱ㈱㤴㈹ര਍楓敺㈽㘵㔰㤲㘶〴ര਍

Comment: Please read [ask]. What were you expecting it to send to the file?

Comment: You are appending to the end of the specified file. Have you tried deleting it first? Also, what code page are you running cmd.exe with? What did you use to view the file? What makes you think the `wmic diskdrive list` command wrote that output?

Comment: How did you launch the script? From a console window, or clicking on the script file from Windows Explorer?

Comment: I am trying to get the Model, Processor, Memory and HD size to export to a txt file. I will be running this on numerous computers we are auctioning for United Way and I am saving the text then printing and I will keep the original for records.

Comment: @jwdonahue not sure the reason you are pointing user to the "how to ask" tutorial. Question is perfectly legit as it is.

Comment: @Gerhard, in that case, you have an answer for the OP? Note the OP's comment regarding the intent of the script? There was missing information in the OP, hence the stream of follow-up questions, some of which could have been avoided if the OP had specified what they have done to debug the problem. Then perhaps, we'd know how it is launched, and what it was that displayed the apparently errant text. So given my questions and the OP's experience at SO, I felt it couldn't hurt to suggest the [ask] link.

Comment: Sorry guys.This is a Batch Script that is on a flash drive and I click it to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this. I made quite a few changes, especially the way you accessed the format of `wmic` output formats. I also used `choice` instead of a bunch of `if` statements.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic systemenclosure get serialnumber /FORMAT:list') do mkdir "%~dp0\ProductCodes\%Serial%" >nul 2>&1
for /f "tokens=2delims==" %%i in ('wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey /format:list') do (echo %%i)>"%~dp0\ProductCodes\%Serial%\code.txt"
(wmic computersystem get model,manufacturer
wmic cpu get name
wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory
wmic diskdrive get size
)> "%~dp0\ProductCodes\%Serial%\PCINFO.txt"

cls
More "ProductCodes\%Serial%\code.txt"
ECHO Open Windows Authentication?
choice /m "Open Authentication?"
if errorlevel 2 goto :message
goto :eof
:Start
start "C:\Windows\System32" slui.exe 3
pause
:message
cls
ECHO Done!!
pause
```

Side note on your original `if %m%==y` statements. You can use `if /i` to make the match case insensitive.. in other words, `if /i "y"=="Y"` will be true as well, but no longer relevant here if using `choice`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It is just what I need. I will learn a lot from this. And thank you to everyone for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try for this modification with piping the command `More` since the output of `WMIC` is UNICODE

---

```bat
@echo off
@for /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in (
    'wmic systemenclosure get serialnumber /FORMAT:csv'
) do (set "serial=%%A")
Set "LogFolder=%cd%ProductCodes\%Serial%"
MkDir "%LogFolder%">nul 2>&1
Set "Code=%LogFolder%\Code.txt"
Set "PCINFO=%LogFolder%\PCINFO.txt"
wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey>"%code%"

(
    wmic computersystem get model,manufacturer
    wmic cpu get name
    wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory
    wmic diskdrive list full ^| findstr /B "Size="
) | More>"%PCINFO%"

More "%Code%"
ECHO Open Windows Authentication?
Echo Y/N
SET /P M=Make Choice then press ENTER:
IF /I %M%==N GOTO :message
IF /I %M%==Y GOTO :Start

:Start
start "C:\Windows\System32" slui.exe 3
 pause

:message
CLS
ECHO Done!!
pause
```

Comment: I will close the post when I find out how. I appreciate the help guys

Comment: @doheth, you cannot close this thread, but you could [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)…

Comment: Thank you aschipfl